CommunityToolkit Mvvm - Namespace not found
I try to reference the communitytoolkit mvvm to use the [ObservableProperty].
I've just created a new Maui APP project from scratch with the standard template (Nice racing car) and it works.
I've installed the Communitytoolkit mvvm and Maui :

But when I add a class like this, it says "CS0246 - The type or namespace name 'ObservableObject' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   BelWriting (net8.0-ios), BelWriting (net8.0-maccatalyst), BelWriting (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0)"
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm;

namespace BelWriting.ViewModels
{
    public partial class MainPageVM : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private int _id;
        [ObservableProperty]
        private string _name;
        [ObservableProperty]
        private string _description;

        [ICommand]
        public async void Save()
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("MAUI MVVM Sample", "Item Saved Successfully", "OK");
        }
    }
}

I try to run this on a windows machine :

This is the content of my csproj file :
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;net8.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <WindowsSdkPackageVersion>10.0.19041.41</WindowsSdkPackageVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">13.1</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

What did I miss ?!?
Did problems comes from the targeted frameworks and how to solve them ?

I think the ObservableObject errors are red-herrings. The [ICommand] attribute looks wrong/obsolete. Isn't it [RelayCommand] now?

You may tried updating the Visual Studio and use the latest .NET8 SDK.

The problem is the following:
namespaces: you need ComponentModel for ObserveableProperty and Object and Input for Command
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;

Then you also need to use [RelayCommand] and not [ICommand] attribute
public partial class MainPageVM : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private int _id;
        [ObservableProperty]
        private string _name;
        [ObservableProperty]
        private string _description;

        [RelayCommand]
        public async Task Save()
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("MAUI MVVM Sample", "Item Saved Successfully", "OK");
        }
    }


according to the docs, ObservableObject is in the Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel namespace, so you need to add a using statement for that namespace
Note that if you right-click on the error, Visual Studio will suggest common solutions to you, including fixing missing using directives

Because that is a different NuGet, at least for now
